# Modificar herramienta OCR

Tags: java, android-studio

Necesitaria saber si es posible modificar la herramienta OCR para android para que solo se quedara con puntos. Solo los puntos, para despues poder contarlos.
Y si no es así, hay alguna alternativa?
Muchas gracias

Comment: Por favor [edit] tu pregunta aclarando: ¿qué es OCR?, ¿qué has intentado?

Comment: a qué te refieres con contar los puntos? @MauricioAriasOlave, OCR = Optical Character Recognition

Comment: @fredyfx, gracias y es bueno que el OP coloque la definición de cada término que use en su pregunta - para efectos de que otros usuarios puedan entender el concepto.

Comment: de nada, dale :D por cierto Marc, bienvenido a la hermandad de SOes :D

Comment: @fredyfx, A contar puntos, me referia a por ejemplo, si hago una foto a un cuadro con muchos puntos(o puntos y cuadrados por ejemplo), que la herramienta me pueda decir cuantos puntos hay en la imagen y omita los cuadrados. Sé que parece una tonteria, pero es para probar una cosita en casa. Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Entiendo, Bueno pienso que tu pregunta puede ir enfocado a dos problemas comunes.

A. Contar puntos.
B. Reconocer otros objetos distintos a letras, que aparezcan en una imagen.
C. es posible también que estés buscando modificar un OCR, pero qué en realidad lo que necesitas es un clasificador de imágenes de aquellos que de una foto te dicen cuantos triángulos, círculos o líneas hay en la imagen.

Un OCR pasan por 4 pasos básicos:

1. mejoramiento de la imagen.
2. segmentación de la imagen.
3. reconocimiento de los símbolos.
4. verificación con diccionarios.

para el problema A, Contar puntos:
si quieres contar puntos como : ......

el mejoramiento de la imagen cuyo objetivo es reducir ruido de la imagen termina borrando los puntos que querías contar en principio porqué los puede confundir por ruido de la imagen.

quizás deberías buscar otras apps que hay en para Android para reconocer objetos o puntos. yo alguna vez probé una cámara que detectaba perfiles y los grababa en formato dxf, trabajaba con la librería CV2 y así creo que si podrías determinar el número de puntos u objetos detectados en la imagen.

si lo que quieres es que no sean letras sino que el OCR reconozca objetos distintos a las letras pero por decir algo repetidos en una imagen puede ser que la segmentación falle y no encierra apropiadamente a los objetos que quieras identificar o contar.

las últimas OCR que trabajan con redes neuronales no creo que te puedan servir porqué estás deben entrenarse con un grupo de prueba y algo me dice que lo que buscas es algo como de inmediatez, sin grandes grupos de imágenes de entrenamiento,  quizás lo que hace más fácil es que nos muestres una imagen con lo que quieres reconocer y una mejor explicación de que es lo que quieres automatizar,

al tomar la imagen con Android deberías guardarlo en algún formato de imagen y con un lenguaje que se ejecute en Android analizar la imagen obtenida con el fin de capturar los pixeles de la imagen, pero difícilmente podrás tener acceso al código del OCR, a menos que se trate de tesseract, porque esta escrito en python y hay versiones de python para Android y el código está en github.

yo creo que lo que buscas es modificar un OCR, pero aun no sabes si es otra tipo de aplicación la que puede darte mejor resultados y ser más fácil de programar.

Comment: Tal y como está redactada, tu respuesta no es clara. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir detalles adicionales que ayuden a los demás a entender cómo esto responde a la pregunta formulada. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).